# htaccess 301 Redirect producing internal server error with complex URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to do the following redirect:

```
Redirect 301 "/cgi-bin/teemz/teemz.cgi?board=_master&action=opentopic&topic=4&forum=The_Forum" "/content/1998-09-10/1004/wet-h2s---hic-concern---ae-amp"
```

And it's resulting in an Internal Server Error.  Can you guys see anything wrong with this code?

Comment: I've also tried using RewriteRule: `RewriteRule ^/cgi\-bin/teemz/teemz\.cgi\?board=_master&action=opentopic&topic=4&forum=The_Forum/?$ /content/1998-09-10/1004/wet-h2s---hic-concern---ae-amp [L,R=301]` to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have some illegal characters such as "/

You need to encode the value of each parameter. I don't know how can you do that in the programming language that you are using but in ASP.NET MVC we have library for that.

```
 public ActionResult Index2()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var key in Request.QueryString.AllKeys)
            sb.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", key, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString[key]));
        var parameters = sb.Remove(0, 1);
        const string rawurl = "http://localhost:49534/home?";
        var url = string.Format("{0}{1}", rawurl, sb);
        return Redirect(url);
    }
```

The encoded parameters will become

board=_master&action=opentopic&topic=4&forum=The_Forum%22+%22%2fcontent%2f1998-09-10%2f1004%2fwet-h2s---hic-concern---ae-amp

But your browser address bar will retain the parameters

"?board=_master&action=opentopic&topic=4&forum=The_Forum"+"%2fcontent%2f1998-09-10%2f1004%2fwet-h2s---hic-concern---ae-amp"

Answer (score 0):

Remember that RewriteRule:

- doesn't match leading slash
- doesn't match query string

Use this Rewrite Rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+cgi-bin/teemz/teemz\.cgi\?board=_master&action=opentopic&topic=4&forum=The_Fo‌​rum [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /content/1998-09-10/1004/wet-h2s---hic-concern---ae-amp [L,R=301]
```